# Creating Dataframes from list of file directories

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a folder of CSV's that I am attempting to read using pandas and create a list of dataframes using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

#create list of file paths
paths = []
for filepath in glob.iglob('Z:/file_path/*'):
    paths.append(filepath)

#create list of dataframes using file paths
df_list = []
for file in paths:
   df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file))
```

However, when I attempt to create the list of dataframes I receive an error: 'EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file'. I've tried adding Header = none, and different separators( ie. sep = "," ) to my df_list.append line, but haven't been able to figure out what is causing the issue.

Comment: The error is saying that the file it wants to parse is empty. Have you check that the file path and the file itself are correct_

Comment: Yes, if I create the list of paths, and then select one to use in a dataframe - such as df = pd.read_csv(paths[0]) I don't receive any errors and when I print df everything looks correct.

Comment: Just put a `print(file)` before the `df_list.append` to debug.  It'll at least tell you which file cause problem.

Comment: probably one of the paths in the list is not actually refering to your csv file since you are using `/*`. As mentioned by @Akarius, print the file paths and you will see what's going on.